# While creating table in db in phpmyadmin i encounter an issue ..... I have attached the code along with the screenshot of the error

Tags: database, phpmyadmin

CREATE TABLE `lab7`.`password` ( `id` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL , `scheme` VARCHAR(25) NULL , `time_input` DOUBLE(25) NULL , `state` VARCHAR(25) NULL , `time_C1` DOUBLE(25) NULL , `state_C1` VARCHAR(25) NULL , `time_C2` DOUBLE(25) NULL , `state_C2` VARCHAR(25) NULL , `time_C3` DOUBLE(25) NULL , `state_C3` VARCHAR(25) NULL , `time_C4` DOUBLE(25) NULL , `state_C4` VARCHAR(25) NULL , `time_C5` DOUBLE(25) NULL , `state_C5` VARCHAR(25) NULL , `time_C6` DOUBLE(25) NULL , `state_C6` VARCHAR(25) NULL , `time_C7` DOUBLE(25) NULL , `state_C7` VARCHAR(25) NULL ) ENGINE = InnoDB;

(following error occurs)

## 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ')NULL, 'state' VARCHAR(25) NULL, 'time_C1' DOUBLE(25) NULL, 'state_C1''VA' at line 1

Comment: You don't need to specify NULL for the fields which can have null values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use decimal instead of double.

```
CREATE TABLE password ( id VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL , scheme VARCHAR(25), time_input decimal(25,2) , state VARCHAR(25), time_C1 decimal(25) , state_C1 VARCHAR(25) , time_C2 decimal(25) , state_C2 VARCHAR(25) , time_C3 decimal(25) , state_C3 VARCHAR(25) , time_C4 decimal(25) , state_C4 VARCHAR(25), time_C5 decimal(25) , state_C5 VARCHAR(25) , time_C6 decimal(25) , state_C6 VARCHAR(25) , time_C7 decimal(25) , state_C7 VARCHAR(25) ) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```